# How to center text from a div from a div

Tags: html, vertical-alignment

I have this situation:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="my-items">
        <div class=m id="id1">
            Smth here(1)
        </div>

        <div class=m id="id2">
            Smth here(2)
        </div>

        <div class=m id="id3">
            Smth here(2)
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I have undetermined number of divs(child of a div(child of a div))

I want to align text vertically(in his div(first text - #id1, second text - #id2...))!
I tried to use `vertical-align: middle;`.
Please create a jsfiddle or codepen example!

CSS:

```
.m{
height:32px;
width:90px;
text-align: center;
}
#my-items{
max-height:400px;
width:90px;
text-align:center;
}
```

[I created a very simple schematic paint 3d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEQmX.png)

Comment: It would help if you showed the CSS that you are having trouble with, and even more if you said why you think it isn't working right.  Also, there are two "id=id2", so I'm guessing one should be "=id3".

Comment: OK! Should I edit and post css?

Comment: I showed my css!

Comment: is it ok? What should I modify?

Comment: Dude, are you still here?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to match the image as much as possible. Hopefully, you can take the code and modify as you need it. If this is not the solution you were looking for, I apologize.

P.S. I added a comment in the css to show you ***one*** way of vertically positioning content.

```css
#my-items{
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  max-height: 400px;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: center;
}

.m{
  height:32px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid black;
  
  /* This is one way of vertially aligning content */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="my-items">
      <div class=m id="id1">
          Smth here(1)
      </div>

      <div class=m id="id2">
          Smth here(2)
      </div>

      <div class=m id="id3">
          Smth here(2)
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your #my-items style

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
```